# Kotlin: Find Count from Nested set in List (more functional approach)

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

Below function creates a Map, gets the count of passengers where passengers are > minTrips. The code works completely fine. Please see below

```
fun List<Trip>.filter(minTrips : Int): Set<Passenger> {
    var passengerMap: HashMap<Passenger, Int> = HashMap()

    this.forEach { it: Trip ->
        it.passengers.forEach { it: Passenger ->
            var count: Int? = passengerMap.get(it)
            if (count == null) {
                count = 1
                passengerMap.put(it, count)
            } else {
                count += 1
                passengerMap.put(it, count)
            }
        }
    }

    val filteredMinTrips: Map<Passenger, Int> = passengerMap.filterValues { it >= minTrips }
    println (" Filter Results = ${filteredMinTrips}")
    return filteredMinTrips.keys
}
```

Even though this is written in Kotlin, it seems like the code was first written in Java and then converted over to Kotlin. If it was truly written in Kotlin I am sure this wouldnt have been so many lines of code. How can I reduce the lines of Code? What would be a more funtional approach to solve this? What function or functions can I use to extract the Passengers Set directly where Passengers are > minTrips? This is too much of a code and seems crazy. Any pointers would be helpful here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way you could do this is to take advantage of Kotlin's flatmap and grouping calls. By creating a list of all passengers on all trips, you can group them, count them, and return the ones that have over a certain number.

Assuming you have data classes like this (essential details only):

```
data class Passenger(val id: Int)
data class Trip(val passengers: List<Passenger>)
```

I was able to write this:

```
fun List<Trip>.frequentPassengers(minTrips: Int): Set<Passenger> =
    this
       .flatMap { it.passengers }
       .groupingBy { it }
       .eachCount()
       .filterValues { it >= minTrips }
       .keys
```

This is nice because it is a single expression. Going through it, we look at each `Trip` and extract all of its `Passengers`. If we had just done `map` here, we would have `List<List<Passenger>>`, but we want a `List<Passenger>` so we flatmap to achieve that. Next, we `groupBy` the `Passenger` objects themselves, and call `eachCount()` on the returned object, giving us a `Map<Passenger, Int>`. Finally we filter the map down the Passengers we find interesting, and return the set of keys.

Note that I renamed your function, `List` already has a `filter` on it, and even though the signatures are different I found it confusing.

Comment: Ok so I didnt knew what flatmap does. Seems really convenient :)

Comment: @Todd : Is there a way to extract two different types of objects (say driver and passenger) from a flat map at a same time?

Comment: @Ahmed yes, you could do this flatMap { it.passenger + it.drivers }.. what the code after that will look like depends on your use case

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to count the trips for each passenger, so you can put all passengers in a list and then group by them and afterwards count the occurences in each group:

```
fun List<Trip>.usualPassengers(minTrips : Int) = // 1
        flatMap(Trip::passengers) // 2
        .groupingBy { it } // 3
        .eachCount() // 4
        .filterValues { it >= minTrips } // 5
        .keys // 6
```

Explanation:

1. return type `Set<Passenger>` can be inferred
2. `this` can be ommitted, a list of the form `[p1, p2, p1, p5, ...]` is returned
3. a [Grouping](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/index.html) is created, which looks like this `[p1=[p1, p1], p2=[p2], ...]]`
4. the number of occurences in each group will be counted: `[p1=2, p2=1, ...]`
5. all elementes with values which less than `minTrips` will be filtered out
6. all keys that are left will be returned `[p1, p2, ...]`

<sub>`p1...pn` are Passenger instances</sub>